# Permalink edit button not showing for pages or posts in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

Using Wordpress Multisite with Wordpress v5.3.2 and Gutenberg Editor, I'm unable to edit permalinks above the title of a page or post. When clicking the title on a page in the editor, I'm presented with the link but no edit button. Is there a function I need to add to the functions.php file in order to enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Changing permalink to posts or pages in Wordpress**

Go to ***Dashboard > Pages > All Pages***. Then on the page list, hover on the page name and click '***Quick Edit***'.

you should see something like this:

[image: change permalink for pages and posts in wordpress]

You can change the slug field by placing the new value. Don't forget to save your changes by clicking on the Update button.

**Note:** I am using version 5.4 and it worked for me. I needed to change some urls for the English version of my website.

Although it was a little late, I decided to answer because other people may be encountering the same problem. I had a lot of difficulty trying to change some urls and only after several attempts I found out by chance.